# Magnetic analog for how charge distributions can be approximated as point charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

I know that far away from a distribution of charges, the fields can be approximated using Gauss' Law, and the fields become very similar to that of a point charge. Is there an analog for this in magnetics?

For example, how would this work for a loop of current, could it be approximated as a "point magnet"? That doesn't seem right to me, so I'm guessing it has no analog.

But if a ball was magnetized, could it be approximated in such a fashion? I guess I am asking, at a sufficient distance from this magnetized ball, what do the nature of the fields caused by the equivalent currents due to its magnetization become "similar to"?

Comment: This article may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Gauss's_law_for_magnetism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop of current can indeed be considered as a small bar magnet with the same magnetic moment as the current loop. Unlike in electrostatics, magnetic monopoles do not exist. The magnetized ball is a magnetic dipole, and hence it will have the same effects as any other magnetic dipole including a current carrying loop, at a large distance.